# What is the difference between window.language and navigator.language?

Tags: javascript

If you open up your console and type in `window.language` and then `navigator.language`, it gives you locales, however they're different for me. Is `window.language` the setting in the browser? That would make sense, but then `navigator` is an object that also contains browser information.

In my specific case,

```
window.language // en-US
navigator.language // ru-RU
```

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language

> The NavigatorLanguage.language read-only property returns a string
>   representing the preferred language of the user, usually the language
>   of the browser UI.

window.language isn't a thing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window so it might be a property set by a javascript library you're using.

[image: window.language is undefined]

Answer (score 2):

[`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language):

> The NavigatorLanguage.language read-only property returns a string representing the preferred language of the user, usually the language of the browser UI.

---

`window.language` is non-standard. When I test its value, it is `undefined`. So it is whatever your webpage sets it to.

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.language` [is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language):

> The `NavigatorLanguage.language` read-only property returns a string representing the preferred language of the user, usually the language of the browser UI.

So it sounds like your browser / OS is set up to prefer Russian. But there's no such thing as `window.language`, at least on Chrome, Firefox, or Opera. If such a variable exists for you, it was probably created by a script which created a `language` variable on the top level (or explicitly on the `window`), eg:

```js
var language = 'en-US';
console.log(window.language);
```